# Doxygen placement of dotfile in html output?

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to include a dot image at the top of a c++ class reference page with the inheritance and collaboration diagrams.  There doesn't appear to be a way to change the placement of the dotfile within a page?

Comment: What do you mean by "dot image" and "dotfile"?

Comment: I used dotfile as it is the special command to include a dot generated file. http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmddotfile

Comment: Just including an image file with placement doesn't appear to be a feature - or I'm not reading the documentation properly.

Comment: Ahhh, I wasn't even aware that Doxygen had support for such a thing! Generally, layout can be controlled by using a custom stylesheet. Generate the output, take a look at the HTML, then get Doxygen to generate you a stylesheet and change the appropriate element's attributes.

Comment: Here's the documentation of that particular feature: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/customize.html#layout

Comment: Doesn't that change the layout of everything?   I'm looking to just monkey with one or two pages.

Comment: Yes, if you change the layout of a "dotfile" element (or whatever Doxygen decides the ID of dot elements ought to be) in the CSS, it will change the layout of every dot. If you only want to rearrange some pages, I don't think there is a way to just change some pages and not others short of defining a new CSS tag and manually editing your HTML output. :(

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I was hoping to not go there.  CSS wasn't something I really wanted to learn about ;-)